# Carrierwave S3 Keep File when Editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have Carrierwave working to upload images to my site and storing them on S3.

However, whenever a user edits a record they have to upload the image again even when they don't need to change it. I want to let the existing image continue to be used unless the user "Chooses" to upload a new image.

Answer (score 2):

In the [carrierwave wiki](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki), you have a section [How to: Keep uploaded files (for a specific uploader)](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Keep-uploaded-files-%28for-a-specific-uploader%29). I don't know if this works with S3, but you may give it a try.

To keep all uploaded files use an initializer like this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false
end
```

If you want to configure that on a per-uploaded basis:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  configure do |config|
    config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I did, but this is working now. While the UI doesn't reflect that the image will still be there, the user doesn't need to upload the picture again.